# How to remove the following error?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

***The question was to find the symmetric difference between two sets without using the the corresponding method !***

from **future** import print_function

```
M=int(raw_input())

X=map(int,raw_input().split())

N=int(raw_input())

Y=map(int,raw_input().split())

mys=set()

mys1=set()

for i in X:

    mys.add(i)

for i in Y:
    mys1.add(i)

un=mys.union(mys1)

inx=mys.intersection(mys1)

sd=un.difference(inx)

w=list(sd)

w=w.sort()

for i in (w):
    print(w[i],end=' ')
```

Error occured is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "hackset.py", line 18, in
<module>
    for i in len(w): TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()**
```

Comment: There is no such line in the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) does not return a new sorted function. It just sort the list (return `None`).

If you want to get a new list sorted, use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) instead.

---

There's another issue. Iterating a list yields elements, you don't need to index them to get items; Just iterate without indexing.

```
for item in w:
    print(item, end=' ')
```

Comment: Thanku for help ! I want to ask one more question that if we edit the code snippet as : `for i in len(w):print (w[i])` ....will this be useful ?  @falsetru

Comment: @PragyanshuBansal, You cannot iterate number (the return value of `len(w)` is a number). You need to use `range` if you want use indexing: `for i in range(len(w)): print(w[i], end=' ')`

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
w=w.sort()
```

The return type for w.sort() is 'None'. The sort() method is in-place. Change it to just:

```
w.sort()
```